# Multiple Image selection from gallery using Cordova Camera plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am making an application based on ionic-1 where I need to take access camera as well as gallery. I used Cordova Camera plugins. It is working properly. Using this plugin we can access not only our device gallery but also our drive, documents etc. But main problem is, I cant select multiple image from gallery. I need to select it one by one.

How may I solve this issue..? I do not want to use cordova image picker plugins.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this issue by using `cordova-imagePicker` plugin. you can access it from [github](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker).

The plugin creates the object `window.imagePicker` with the method
`getPictures(success, fail, options)`.

with this plugin you can select multiple photos

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    } ); Example - Get at most 10 images scaled to width of 800:

window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }, {
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width: 800
    } );
```

Comment: please note that `maximumImagesCount` is not working for iOS in the latest versions of the plugin

Comment: I tried this in android where it is working perfectly not in ios so i am unable to solve your problem